# Magento 2: I Want to add multiple product using checkbox

Tags: magento2

"**I Want to add multiple product using checkbox**" but when I am doing that thing then it'll add to cart successfully but it sets product price as $0.00. I am using simple product.

1. Request.php- Controller

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Deep\Module\Controller\Index;

   use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
   use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
   use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
   use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;

   class Request extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
   {
       protected $formKey;
       protected $_productFactory;
       protected $_cart;   
       protected $messageManager;
       public function __construct(
           Context $context,
           \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
           \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $managerInterface,
           \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
           \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
           Session $session,
           QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
       ) {
           parent::__construct($context);
           $this->formKey = $formKey;
           $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
           $this->_cart = $cart;
           $this->messageManager = $managerInterface;
           $this->session = $session;
           $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
       }
       /**
         * Booking action
         *
         * @return void
         */
       public function execute()
       {
           // 1. POST request : Get booking data
           $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

           if (!empty($post)) {
               // Retrieve your form data
               $firstname   = $post['fname'];
               $lastname    = $post['lname'];
               $email       = $post['email'];
               $phone       = $post['phone'];
               $comment     = $post['comment'];
               $product     = $post['chk'];
               // $newsletter  = $post['newsletter'];

               if($product){
                   foreach ($product as $value) {
                       if (isset($value)) {
                           $this->addCartProduct($value);
                       }
                       $this->_cart->save();
                   }
                   // Doing-something with...
                   $quoteId = $this->session->getQuote()->getId();
                   // echo $quoteId;exit(); 

                   if ($quoteId) {
                       $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
                       if (!$quote->getIsActive()) {
                           return;
                       }

                       // $product = $observer->getEvent()->getDataByKey('add_data');

                       /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
                       $item = $this->session->getQuote();//->getItemByProduct($product);
                       $quote->setFname($firstname);
                       $quote->setLname($lastname);
                       $quote->setEmail($email);
                       $quote->setPhone($phone);
                       $quote->setComment($comment);

                       $quote->save();
                   }

                   // Display the succes form validation message

                   $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Quote Request Accepted...!!!');

                   // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
                   $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                   $resultRedirect->setPath('module/index/request');

                   return $resultRedirect;
               }
           }

           // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
           $this->_view->loadLayout();
           $this->_view->renderLayout();
       }

       public function addCartProduct($productID)
       {
           $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productID);
           $info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
               [
                   'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                   'product_id' => $productID,
                   'price' =>$product->getPrice()
               ]
           );
           return $this->_cart->addProduct($product, $info);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: have you print_r($product->getData()) there . Just check are you getting price attribute in product data else load product and add loadded product to cart

Comment: This is my code please give splution of this problem

Comment: have you tried below code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @Deep You should get all selected checkbox's product id then load each product and perform add to cart.

Comment: yes I did this and it's saved my time thank you sagar

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productID);
    $info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product' => $productID
        ]
    );
    return $this->_cart->addProduct($product, $info);
```

Comment: i am already using this code but it's not wirking, because i want to get price  of priduct whose current id is $productId and i want to add proce of rhat perticuler producr in mini cart ehile add to cart.